# Save double in flutter Moor database

Tags: android, ios, flutter

I am currently working on a little flutter app, and i want to create a local database to cache some data.
one of my fields happens to be a Double, but from documentation and online examples and other searches i can only see these five data types:

```
TextColumn 
IntColumn
BlobColumn
BoolColumn
DateTimeColumn
```

i want to be able to store a variable as a double int the moor table

Any advice on how can i save this field, or do i have to convert it to a string and vice versa during read and write operations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is `RealColumn` ([was added in version 1.4.0](https://github.com/simolus3/moor/blob/master/moor/CHANGELOG.md#140)).